# Modal bottom sheet on flutter with interactive background

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to dim (gray) the background when the bottom sheet opens, like a modal bottom sheet, but still be able to interact with the rest of the UI while the bottom sheet is open  - like a regular bottom sheet.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show something relatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though, I won't recommend creating such an effect as it is not very understandable from the user perspective.

You can achieve this by using the `IgnorePointer`, `Stack` and `setState((){})`

1- Add a field `bool showOverlay = false`;

2- `Align` some `Container` to with `Alignment.bottom` to represent ur bottom sheet

3- Put some overlay `Container` with some background color and opacity and wrap it with `IgnorePointer(ignoring: true, ...)` which will let it not interfere with your widgets below.

I think you got it from here.

Comment: Thanks, Karim. Thought about it for a while. Like you said, it might confuse the user. So decided against it. Thanks. :)

Comment: At least provide code example, how can this even be helpful

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make a stack and then

```
///
 your widget

////
DraggableScrollableSheet widget 
use  DraggableScrollableSheet(builder:(context, scrollController) => Container(
                    height: 100.h,
                    width: 360.w,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),)
```